# Joomla 2.5 Delete query with LEFT JOIN

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Im trying to implement delete code with LEFT JOIN in Joomla 2.5:

```
$cid = JRequest::getVar('cid', array(), 'post', 'array');

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->delete($db->quoteName('table1').' AS t1');

$query->leftJoin($db->quoteName('table2').
' AS t2 ON t2.table_1_id = t1.id ');

$query->where(array('t1.id IN ('.  implode(',', $cid).')'));

$db->setQuery($query);

try {
  $db->query(); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

What I get is:

```
DELETE FROM `table1` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `table2` AS t2 ON t2.table_1_id = t1.id 
WHERE t1.id IN (48)
```

This SQL query is incorrect. What I need is:

```
DELETE t1.*,t2.* FROM `table1` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `table2` AS t2 ON t2.table_1_id = t1.id 
WHERE t1.id IN (48)
```

So how I should change Joomla query to get the right SQL query? Any ideas?

Comment: Try chaining ->columns(t1.*, t2.*)     The delete is odd in that it clearly only puts the table.

Comment: Nope, this does not work either.

Comment: if you do $query->delete() it will delete the whole row. Just happened to see this in JTableUser   $query->delete(); query->from('#__user_usergroup_map');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been working with Joomla for a long time now. According to my Joomla knowledge you can't accomplish what you are trying to do `$query->delete()`. Since your query is a bit tricky it can be executed using below method.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "DELETE t1.*,t2.* FROM `table1` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `table2` AS t2 ON t2.table_1_id = t1.id 
WHERE t1.id IN (48)"; // you can replace the line with array('t1.id IN ('.  implode(',', $cid).')')
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll stick to your method. Actually it is the same manner it was done in Joomla v1.5. So anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: yeah for the time being that's all we can do. But I hope there will be a fix in the future :-)

Comment: I solved my issue with this method. I had problemas with $query->delete() too. Thanks!